# Entity Framework Core Composite Key In One To Many Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So have an issue coming up with mapping where we have two classes

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id;
    public CustomerAddress StatementAddress
    public bool AlwaysTrue => true;
    public string Code;
}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    public int Id;
    public bool ForStatement;
    public string _CustomerCode
}
```

We than have a mapping set up like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasOne(s => s.StatementAddress)
        .WithMany()
        .HasPrincipalKey(x=> new {x._CustomerCode, x.ForStatement})
        .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.Code, s.AlwaysTrue});
}
```

This is however causing an issue, as it seems to be on the database looking for a column of StatementAddress_CustomerCode and StatementAddress_ForStatement within the Customer table, which clearly are not things that exist - why isnt it looking for the Code table and simply passing through True for the AlwaysTrue?

I would have thought the way its defining keys would just Use the Code and Alwaystrue value, but seems to be looking for two columns made up of a combination of the Property name, appended with the property name from the other class =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to close this out -

This is something not currently possible in EF Core (2.1) and remains to be seen if it will be added in future versions - as present it only supports mapping through a single property

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things here:

1. You can either manually define column names like this:

   ```
   public class Customer
   {
       public int Id;
       public CustomerAddress StatementAddress;
       [Column("StatementAddress_ForStatement")]
       public bool AlwaysTrue => true;
       [Column("StatementAddress_CustomerCode")]
       public string Code;
   }
   ```
2. You can specify the foreign key with the `ForeignKeyAttribute` like this:

   ```
   public class Customer
   {
       public int Id;
       public CustomerAddress StatementAddress;
       [ForeignKey("StatementAddress"), Column(Order = 1)]
       public bool AlwaysTrue => true;
       [ForeignKey("StatementAddress"), Column(Order = 0)]
       public string Code;
   }
   ```

   Keep in mind that for this option you have to set the column order attribute to match the one that the foreign key in the `CustomerAddress` table has.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, marking the fields with a Column attribute wouldnt really help as it would just be specifying that those are the column names on the database - when they arent.

marking individual attributes with foreign key seems a little odd to me? like according to the microsoft docs on EF core to set up a composite key you cant do it that way?

Comment: If you are using code first migrations, with the column attribute those would become the column names. As far as the ForeignKey attribute goes, can you provide a link to the Microsoft docs part that says it cannot be used that way? Because as far as I can see, EF core supports the attribute.

Comment: Hey, not using migrations at all - running in a Database first style as the database itself is actually 3rd party so non-editable or it would break other systems.